# ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager

Tags: grails, plugins

I'm getting this error on grails 2.4.3. Any solution?

This is all I get when I run the app:

```
2014-11-01 00:39:36,359 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [controllers:2.4.3]: String index out of range: 1
Message: String index out of range: 1
    Line | Method
->> 1907 | substring                     in java.lang.String
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    222 | getPropertyNameRepresentation in grails.util.GrailsNameUtils
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                           in java.lang.Thread
|Server running. Browse to http://MYSERVER/MPC_NuevosIngresos
```

I do get more errors later if I try browsing into the application, but I guess they're caused by this.

My BuildConfig only contains this:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
         runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

So I have absolutely no clue about what might be causing this. Help would be massively appreciated

Also, I don't think it's very relevant to this error, but I'm using a legacy database, and this is an example of how I'm trying to map my legacy domains, since they have a String assigned id, and not an auto generated one. This error started happening right after I implemented this, though I'm not really sure it's related.

```
class AceDistrito {

    String id;
    static transients = ['theId']
    void setTheId(String theId) {
        id = theId
    }
    String getTheId() {
        return id
    }

    String canton
    String nombre

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'distritos'
        version false
        autoTimestamp false
        datasource 'ace'
        id column: 'distrito', generator:'assigned', type:'string'
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you upgraded your App from some previous version?

Comment: You can try grails clean; grails compile ; grails run-app.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I "fixed" it. Nothing really worked, I tried clean, recompile, delete target, rerun. Nothing worked.
Had to create a new project and copy all the sources as I had them, regenerate views and controllers and it worked. Old project was corrupted somehow.